# Why does Google Chrome fail to draw tabs correctly when the Discrete graphics adapter is in use?

Tags: display, google-chrome, gpu, web-browser, video-adapter

Google Chrome fails to paint browser tabs correctly while the Discrete graphics adapter is in use.

I have an Early 2011 15" MacBook Pro running OSX 10.10.5 (Yosemite) and am running Chrome Version 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit). This problem began about a month ago.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is still relevant to you but maybe this will help you:

[MacBook Pro Repair Extension Program for Video Issues](https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/)

Basically your GPU might be faulty and Apple will fix it for free.

Comment: Heh, already had this machine repaired to address that very issue some time ago. The symptoms were very different though.